# Check if username exists, not working

Tags: php, html, forms, url, registration

I've created a registration form, yesterday I've created an 'admin' account, but this morning I've noticed that:

1. I can create another admin account, while yesterday I could not.
2. If I create an account called 'user' I can't create another account named 'user' BUT if I try to create an account named 'user' after rebooting my pc I can.

Thing's I've tried:
 1. GET method instead of POST, but this inserts the account details into the URL, this is 'bad practice'
 2.

```
$queryc = mysql_query("SELECT `naam` FROM `account` WHERE `naam`='" . $dumpname."'");
if ($wachtwoord == $wachtwoord2 && mysql_num_rows($queryc) == 0) {
```

I've tried the code above, but even that didn't work.

My code:

variables to make the code nicer:

```
$strlow = strtolower($naam);
$dumpname = filter_var($strlow,FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$dumpww = filter_var($wachtwoord,FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$dumpe = filter_var($email,FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$naam = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$wachtwoord = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'wachtwoord');
$wachtwoord2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'wachtwoord2');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
```

if statement:

```
if ($wachtwoord == $wachtwoord2 && $Checknaam['naam'] != $dumpname) {


       $query = "INSERT INTO `account`(`naam`, `wachtwoord`, `email`) VALUES ('$dumpname','$dumpww','$dumpe')";
    $database = $db->query($query);
    $print = "<h2 id='regigoed'>Succesvol geregistreerd je kan nu <a href='reducation.php' class='link'>inloggen!</a></h2>";
} else { //anders print een fout, zonder te veel informatie te geven over de database
    $print = "<div id='regifout'>
                    <h2>Fout het account is niet gemaakt probeer het opnieuw.</h2>
                        <form action='registeraccept.php' method='post'>
                            <p id='paddingregi'> *Account naam: <input id='paddingform' type='text' class='margin' name='name' maxlength='16'></p>
                            <p id='paddingregi'> *Wachtwoord: <input id='paddingform' type='password' class='margin' name='wachtwoord' maxlength='20'></p>
                            <p id='paddingregi'> *Vul je wachtwoord opnieuw in: <input id='paddingform' type='password' class='margin' name='wachtwoord2' maxlength='20'></p>
                            <p id='paddingregi'> *E-mail: <input id='paddingform' type='text' class='margin' name='email' maxlength='50'></p>
                            <input type='submit' value='Registreer' style='margin-left: 10px;'><br>
                        </form>
                        <p id='req'> Velden met * moeten worden ingevuld, u kunt maximaal 20 karakters gebruiken voor uw wachtwoord. </p>
                </div>";
}
```

form:

```
    <form action='registeraccept.php' method='post'>
        <p id='paddingregi'> *Account naam: <input id='paddingform' type='text' class='margin' name='name' maxlength="16"></p>
        <p id='paddingregi'> *Wachtwoord: <input id='paddingform' type="password" class='margin' name='wachtwoord' maxlength="20"></p>
        <p id='paddingregi'> *Vul je wachtwoord opnieuw in: <input id='paddingform' type='password' class='margin' name='wachtwoord2' maxlength="20"></p>
        <p id='paddingregi'> *E-mail: <input id='paddingform' type="text" class='margin' name='email' maxlength="50"></p>
        <input type='submit' value='Registreer' style='margin-left: 15px'><br>
    </form>
```

Does anyone know why I can create 2 users with the same name, if one is created prior to me rebooting, and if the other is made afterwards.

Comment: if the table field is not `unique` you can create as many users with the same name as you have space!

Comment: could you please send where you defined the $wachtwoord, $wachtwoord2 variables ?

Comment: check unique constraint on naam ? and sanitize it with mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: Any errors you getting?

Comment: `Does anyone know why I can create 2 users with the same name, if one is created prior to me rebooting, and if the other is made afterwards.` make sure the naam field is ticket with unique within `mysql`, that way no 2 users can be named the same. Probably you only have a unique value set opun the primary id, which is auto increment.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injections by the way. Well some of it. http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: Before inserting in the database check if the username is already there. `$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);` You can return the amount of rows and then you make an 'if' 'else' statement. If it returns 1 row, you know that there is a user with that name. Else: continue.

Comment: @Mikey I've tried that but it didn't work, I'm not getting any error's, and thank you for the hint regarding SQL injections

Comment: The problem here is your actually checking if a username exists with (AND) the provided password. This is why u can register multiple same usernames, if you use another password

Comment: @Gerwin: have you actually looked in the database after rebooting and before trying againg. Could it be simply a problem with your computer not saving data?

Comment: @DarkBee Actually, with wachtwoord and wachtwoord2 I'm checking if the 2 password fields entered are the same, then I check if the any of the names in the database equal the user entered name, if this is the case then it will go into the else, I don't check for passwords already in the database

Comment: @Mikey yes i've looked in the database after and prior to rebooting

Comment: @Dorvalla found it, thank you for the tip

Comment: @Dorvalla I've just changed it to unique, it doesn't insert it into the database anymore, thank you, but it still says that i've succesfully registered, is there anyway to check for this, other than checking afterwards

Comment: Another if-else statement. If the name already excists (make sure you check that in your if else statement) print out an error message telling it is already registered. I would do a unique field on the email as well, if i were you. Avoiding duplicate accounts from the same mail. Makes it harder for spammers to register. I would apply as well a mail checker script to see if the emails excist.

Comment: @Dorvalla alright thank you for the tips and information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something like this and you should indeed use mysql**i** or PDO.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Make variables here

$sql="SELECT naam FROM account WHERE naam=$dumpname";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {

  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if($rowcount==1){
      die("a user already exists with this username");
  }

  else {
  // proceed with inserting data here    
  }
 }
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look into the mysqli method

Answer (score 0):

Before your insert query, you should check if that username is already present in the database.

And the field username has to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your validation is wrong at this point. If you want to check if an username in the database you should only check the username and not the username AND password, something you are doing at this point. It also uncertain from where the vars `$password` and `$password2` are comming from.

In short u need to adjust your code to something like :

```
$queryc = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM `account` WHERE `naam`='" . $dumpname."'");
if (mysql_num_rows($queryc) == 0) {
    //username is not taken
    //do logic here
}
```

Sidenote :

There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future and start using prepared statements.

Comment: The check for passwords checks if the passwords entered in the 2 seperate fields are the same, not the password in the database